# Questions regarding replacement Trane AC condenser motor

Tags: hvac, electric-motor

A few weeks ago the condenser motor on our Trane XB 10 heatpump was making a screeching sound. I banged it with my fist and the sound stopped but I think it is not long for this world. This unit is about 17 years old. The motor is a GE unit with the part number 5kcp39fg v442as

I have twice ordered the specific OEM motor only to be sent the wrong motor.   I'm now searching out a generic replacement.

The motor on my heat pump mounts with self-tapping screws through the grill into the motor body.  Almost all motors I have found with the same stats are mounted with bolts on the end of the motor that pass through the grill and are bolted to it.  I discovered that those bolts can be reversed or trimmed so that they will not interfere.   This motor is a "frame 48".  Are the holes in the body of the pump for mounting with the self-tapping screws common to all such motors?  Or is this a Trane specific mounting method and I need to find an OEM Motor?

If it comes to it I could simply drill holes in the grill and mount the motor using the bolts.

Comment: Are there ports to oil the motor?

Comment: My understanding is that these motors do not have ports intended for oiling.  There are some holes on it but I think they are intended for drainage should water condense in it.

Comment: A few pictures would help all concerned.

Answer (score 1):

If it's making noise, and is on the exterior of the AC unit, it is likely *not* the condenser motor itself, but a separate **fan motor** and/or its bearings making that noise, as shown in [the circuit diagram](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0f/85/86/0f8586a4ef3dc8630a56f782e21f0b7a.jpg).

This makes it much easier to fix, since a condenser compressor motor is part of a sealed system that requires specialized high-vacuum equipment to service.

First, try applying a *little* ordinary motor oil, e.g. 10W30, to the shaft at each end of the motor. Use a needle-type applicator or basting syringe to the shaft itself, to any bearings, and, if there are holes *just* above the shaft, a few drops in each. Avoid dripping oil on rubber vibration isolators and don't over-oil. Run the AC for a while to see if that fixes the squeak.

This may not be a long-term fix, but should give you time to obtain the equivalent **fan** motor, which can easily be substituted with one of similar size, power, speed and electrical requirements.